# Index doesn't appear in url as expected, so AJAX calls go towrong location - MVC Routing AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an application where if I click on a link (in /ImagesList/Index.cshtml) it will send me to a view in another directory (/ImagesAnalysis/...). Via a controller function that loads some data.

The problem I have is that I would expect to have the url /ImageAnalysis/Index but I actually have just /ImageAnalysis

ImagesList Controller

```
    public ActionResult View(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Open", "ImagesAnalysis", new { id = id });
    }
```

ImagesAnalysis Controller

```
    public ActionResult Open(int id)
    {
        //Load up items from DB

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (Session["img"] == null)
        {
            Session["img"] = new ImageModel();
        }

        return View((ImageModel)Session["img"]);
    }
```

The problem then is my Ajax call go the the wrong location

/ImagesAnalysis/Index.cshtml

```
$("#ImageAccordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SetActiveImage",
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                ImageNumber: this.id,
            },
            success: function (Data) {
                drawing.src = "/Images/" + Data;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

when using firebug the ajax call goes to url /SetActiveImage instead of /ImagesAnalysis/SetActiveImage

Answer (score 1):

Use the full URL path.=>Simple answer.

Usually when situations like this occur, its a configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, that works. Ill have to try and rout out the configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Url helper to generate your path

```
url: '@Url.Action("SetActiveImage", "ImagesAnalysis")'
```